# How to overwrite DefinitelyTyped or reference a custom file

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using a Node library (https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client) and when using VSCode, it automagically pulls in a community-written Type definition (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/solr-client).

My problem is that this is missing methods, or I prefer to have some methods return a more precise Type (specific my project).

For my own code, I can use

```
/** 
 * @typedef {Number} CustomType
 */
```

**Question**

How can I create a separate file and add/modify the types of an existing definition.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the types were declared (either a namespace or module) you can create a type definition file `*.d.ts` and add your declarations there to be merged.

An example I have for jest matchers:

```
declare namespace jest {
  interface Matchers<R> {
    toHave(expected: string): R
  }
}
```

Make sure your definition files are included in the files your `tsconfig` is looking at.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html